# Overloaded final function in derived class

Tags: c++, c++11, polymorphism, overloading, final

How can I use final overloaded function from derived class?
Compiler says 'no matching function for call to 'B::foo()''.

```
class A
{
public:
    virtual void foo() final
    {
        std::cout << "foo";
    }
    virtual void foo(int b) = 0;
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    void foo(int b) override
    {
        std::cout << b;
    }
};

//Somewhere
B* b = new B;
b->foo(); //Error
```

But it works without overloading.

```
class A
{
public:
    virtual void foo() final
    {
        std::cout << "foo";
    }
};

class B : public A
{
};

//Somewhere
B* b = new B;
b->foo(); //Works!
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This declaration in class B

```
void foo(int b) override
{
    std::cout << b;
}
```

hides all other  functions with the same name declared in class A (excluding of course the overriden function).

You can either call the function explicitly like this

```
b->A::foo();
```

Or include using declaration

```
using A::foo;
```

in the definition of class B.

Or you can cast the pointer to the base class pointer

```
static_cast<A *>( b )->foo();
```